# Make [home] a synonym of [home-directory] and merge the two tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request

There are

- 135 questions tagged [home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/home)
- 52 questions tagged [home-directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/home-directory)

The excerpts for both are nearly the same, implying the same use:

[home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/home):

> Questions about users' home folders or the actual /home directory are appropriate.

[home-directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/home-directory)

> The home directory is the directory in which all the user's files reside. The Documents folder, Pictures, and settings reside in this directory, under /home/username on the filesystem.

I don't see why we need two tags for the same, please consider making [home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/home) a synonym of [home-directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/home-directory) and merge the 2 tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes.

They are the same, etc etc etc.

Completed. Thank you for your attention to detail, etc etc etc. :)

Answer (score 1):

### No.

They mean something completely different.